# How can I label the x-axis with $\ln(\varepsilon_{max})$?

Tags: plotting

I want to label the x-axis with $\ln(\varepsilon_{max})$.

And at the same time, I want to label the y-axis as $\ln(t)$.

How to do it?

Answer (score 3):

> How can I label the x-axis with ln(εmax)?

One possibility might be to use [MaTeX](https://github.com/szhorvat/MaTeX), a package for rendering $\LaTeX$ in notebooks:

```
<< MaTeX`
texStyle = {FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman", FontSize -> 14};

yLabel = MaTeX["\\ln(t)", Magnification -> 2];
xLabel = MaTeX["\\ln{\\left(\\epsilon_{\\text{max}}\\right)}",Magnification -> 2];
title = MaTeX["\\text{My Plot}", Magnification -> 2];

Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{yLabel, None}, {xLabel, title}},BaseStyle -> texStyle]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Another option

```
yLabel = TraditionalForm[Log[x]];
xLabel = TraditionalForm[Log[Subscript[\[CurlyEpsilon], max]]];
title = "My Plot";

Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{yLabel, None}, {xLabel, title}},
 BaseStyle -> 14]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: So, you cannot do it within Mathematica alone?